# Using eval() in Vue2 inside a method works and doesn't work at the same time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eval

I have a list of function names inside a component, and depending on certain conditions, different functions must be called from the same place.

I was not able to create a dynamic function in my template, so I created a function 'callMethod(name)' which does an eval. 
The eval WORKS, i.e. it calls a method in my component which then calls a method in the parent. 
However, I get a console error
`enter code here`TypeError: this.myFunctionName(...) is not a function

While everything is working, I don't want these errors puked into my console.

If I comment out the the eval statement, and explicitly type out the method, then it runs as well, but without the error.

if

```
  callMethod(name) {
        eval('this.' + name + '()');
        //this.clickShowDeleteAcceptForm()
        console.log('did I get here?')
    },
```

is called with name='clickShowDeleteAcceptForm' then I get it working with the error, as explained. The console output does not happen.

```
    callMethod(name) {
        //eval('this.' + name + '()');
        this.clickShowDeleteAcceptForm();
        console.log('did I get here?')

    },
```

if I call this (obviously the 'name' variable is irrelevant) then it works without the error! Console output does happen.

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.clickShowDeleteAcceptForm(...) is not a function"

found in

---> <MessagesGuest> at src/components/ManageMessages/Guest.vue
       <ManageMessages> at src/components/ManageMessages/MessagesListing.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1874
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1869
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1835
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1852
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2169
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6855
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1878 TypeError: this.clickShowDeleteAcceptForm(...) is not a function
    at eval (eval at callMethod (Guest.vue?cfd3:95), <anonymous>:1:33)
    at VueComponent.callMethod (Guest.vue?cfd3:106)
    at click (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"6235b99d-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/ManageMessages/Guest.vue?
```

Comment: eval is evil, and you're abusing it. In case you want a method to be specified dynamically, it's as simple as this[name]() (as the answer that was likely based on previously published comment suggests). And callMethod is likely redundant because you could do that in parent scope. In case you want to solve an issue with eval, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem. It should work where you use it, so it's specific to your build.

Comment: Thank - no if eval is not correct in Vue, then I'll stick with the recommended practice. I am not sure what you mean about redundancy and doing it in parent scope. I tried adding @click.stop="this[option.method]() /@click.stop="[option.method]() but neither work, but not sure that is what you mean. If I could call the dynamic method from the template code, then I could lose 'callMethod'.

Comment: eval isn't correct anywhere where an alternative exists. I'd expect `@click.stop="this[option.method]"` to work, in case `this[option.method]` method really exists. Notice that you don't even need `()` there.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck. this[option.method] ->  Cannot read property 'clickAccept' of null,   [option.method] -> nothing, [option.method]()  -> [option.method] is not a function. The methods 100% exist, as they work with my callMethod method.. Vue is confusing, I don't know if I should refer to these things as methods or functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what is the problam but using `eval` is a big No No.
Use this insted:

```
callMethod(name) {
    this[name]();
    //this.clickShowDeleteAcceptForm()
    console.log('did I get here?')
},
```

Comment: Works beautifully, thanks! In the process of changing this, I also realized that some of my method names erroneously had brackets, so the method were being called with double brackets by the eval, hence it working and then throwing an error.. Thanks again for setting me on the right path here.